# Text is not showing on image create by gd library

Tags: php, file, gd, gdlib

i have developed this code for image but the problem is that my text is not appearing on this image please help ! code is running fine with no error. Displaying the white image as mentioned in this code.

```
<?php
//Set the Content Type
header('Content-type: image/jpg');

$w=730;
$h=450;

$image=imagecreate($w,$h);
$text='hello world';

$whitebackground=imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

$blacktext=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$font =$font_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/themify.ttf';

imagettftext($image,40,0,50,50,$blacktext,$font,$text);
imagejpeg($image);

ini_set("log_errors", 1); ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
?>
```

Comment: You should really set your logging config *before* calling functions. By the time you do it here, it's too late to capture anything useful.

Comment: how to do this i'm new to php

Comment: Just move the line with the `ini_set` calls to the top.

Comment: log file is empty

Answer (score 0):

I've run the following code and it is working fine. Only change is font type, I've used the arial.ttf font.  I've attached the output file.

```
<?php
//Set the Content Type
header('Content-type: image/jpg');

$w=730;
$h=450;

$image=imagecreate($w,$h);
$text='hello world';

$whitebackground=imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

$blacktext=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$font =$font_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/arial.ttf';

imagettftext($image,40,0,50,50,$blacktext,$font,$text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much i haven't tried yet but i think it will be running fine. So. why it is not working that given font?